# Titlebar shrinks when I specify a minSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest

I am trying to specify the minSDKVersion:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" />
```

Whenever I add this line, my titlebar shrinks a little bit. Not sure why? When this line is not in my manifest, everything is fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0" package="org.stocktwits.activity">
       <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/Theme.DarkGradient" android:debuggable="false">
        <activity android:name=".Main"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <activity android:name="AddStocksActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="DetailsActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="ChartsActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="ARActivity">
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

**Update:**
I noticed when I set the minimum level to 3 the titlebar size does not shrink. Anything above will shrink. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it has to do with scaling, if API level>3 supports_screens attributes will all be set to true more info here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html